# how do I extract strain and its coordinates with Abapy?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to extract the Strain data from an obd file.
I have found out that I can use these commandlines:

odb.steps[ stepname ].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['LE'].values[1].data[0]

odb.steps[ stepname ].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['LE'].values[1].data[1]

to access LE11 and LE22.
But how do i get where these strains are located?
In oher words; how do I get the coordinates associated with these values?

Kind regards,
Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually more tedious than you would imagine. I'll just outline here:

assuming you have requested integration point field data, obtain element and integration point from

```
  val=odb.steps[ stepname ].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['LE'].values[1]
  lab=val.elementLabel
  ip=val.integrationPoint
```

get the element and connectivity:

```
  el=instance.getElementFromLabel(lab)
  c=el.connectivity
```

then the nodal coordinates..

```
  instance.getNodeFromLabel(c[0]).coordinates
```

finally you need to manually calculate the integration point coordinate from the nodal coordinates and your knowledge of the element type  / shape function.  If you want the deformed position you need to grab the nodal displacements and do that math as well.

Its a bit simpler if you request nodal average field values, but the same basic procedure.

Note depending on your output requests you can have both integration point and nodal data. In that case you need to check `val.position` to see what type you have.

Comment: I have writtenmore code:
`frame = odb.steps[ stepname ].frames[-1]
strainField = frame.fieldOutputs['LE']
for i in range( len(strainField.values)):
   curElemLabel = strainField.values[i].elementLabel
   ip = strainField.values[i].integrationPoint
   el = instance.getElementFromLabel(curElemLabel)
   conn = el.connectivity
   coord = instance.getNodeFromLabel(conn[0]).coordinates
   LE11 = strainField.values[i].data[0]
   LE22 = strainField.values[i].data[1]
   LE12 = strainField.values[i].data[3]`
when i run it, i get odbError: Element index not found"
(for line el=...)

Comment: whats the value of `curElemLabel` ?

Comment: it's the same as lab that you suggested ( `curElemLabel = strainField.values[i].elementLabel` ) . in my simulation it goes from 1 to +/- 5900 (as it stands for the label of the element where i want to get the strain data from)

Comment: @Theodoor You have elementLabels that go to the negatives? That doesn't sound right..

Comment: i meant what is the specific numerical value that is causing the error. use a `print` statement to see what it is.

Comment: it's in a loop. So curElemLabel starts at the value 1 and ends at value 59584.
I deleted all code that belonged to writing the info to a notepad file and added a few print commands. now it works!
i have no idea why because it had nothing to do with curElemLabel but thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: now i'd like to use these coordinates in a different python script.
do you know of a good way to do this?
save the coordinates and values in a notpad or excel file and read these via the second script?
or is there an easier way to do this?
(i don't know if i should start a different thread for this or not)

Comment: very easy, google python file io.  I'd stick with a plain space delimited text file.

Comment: seems i forgot to calculate the integration point coordinate..
after extracting this information i need to interpolate the values anyway, so i think getting the values at nodal coordinates is preferable.
(i have checked and `val.position` gives me INTEGRATION_POINT)
So how do i make sure my output request gives nodal data?